# How to show that a number isn't an element of the ring of algebraic integers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have $\alpha = 2^{1/3}$ , $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ a number field and $O_{K} = \mathbb{Z}(\alpha)$, the ring of algebraic integers in $K$. I want to be able to show that no number of the form $\frac{x + y \alpha + z \alpha^{2}}{2}$ can be in $O_K$, where $x , y , z \in \{0 , 1 \}$ are not all zero. I know that I might want to use the norm and/or the complex embeddings in some way but I'm really not sure how to go about it (even though I feel like the answer will be obvious).
I know there are a lot of ways to show that an element is in $O_{K}$, but I'm not sure how to show that it's not.

Comment: I think I can use the Norm - by showing that it can't possibly be an integer, it means that $\alpha$ can't be an algebraic integer? Would this be the right approach? My only concern is that I feel like there's a more efficient method than going case by case for all the possible combinations of $a , b$ and $c$.

Comment: Finding $\mathcal{O}_K$ may be a bit tricky by paper & pencil in general (even though there are algorithms). IIRC in the simple method you begin by using the trace (the trace of an algebraic integer must be a rational integer) to bound the denominators of the coordinates w.r.t to some integral monomial basis (generating a subring of a finite index). Then you can check the cosets one by one...

Comment: Apologies Dietrich I've edited it to be more accurate. But I'm still unsure how to solve the problem.

Comment: one way is to show that the ideal $(2)$ factors like you would expect it to in $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ (if $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ were missing some integers, that would screw up the factorization in some way)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following method works only for this special cute case:

*Fact 1:* $\frac{\alpha^2}{2}$ is not integral, by looking at its minimal polynomial.

*Fact 2:* If $\beta := \frac{x + y\alpha + z\alpha^2}{2}$ is integral, then $\alpha\beta = z + \frac{x\alpha + y\alpha^2}{2}$ is integral, and so is $\frac{x\alpha + y\alpha^2}{2}$, and so is $\frac{x\alpha^2}{2}$ by similar argument. Hence $x = 0$, and similar arguments show $y=z=0$.

Comment: Can I just clarify; are you sure that just because $z + \frac{x \alpha + y \alpha^2}{2}$ is integral, $\frac{x \alpha + y \alpha^2}{2}$ is also integral? For example $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2}$ is integral since it's just the number $2$, but neither $\frac{1}{2}$ nor $\frac{3}{2}$ are.

Comment: * since their minimal polynomials do not have integer coefficients

Comment: I am using your notations that $x, y, z \in \{0,1\}$. As integral elements form a ring, and $z$ is integral, there is no problem in this case.

Comment: That makes sense - thank you for the clarification!